# C# Best way to retrieve strings that's in quotation mark?

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

Suppose I am given a following text (in a string array)

```
engine.STEPCONTROL("00000000","02000001","02000043","02000002","02000007","02000003","02000008","02000004","02000009","02000005","02000010","02000006","02000011");
    if("02000001" == 1){
        dimlevel = 1;
    }
    if("02000001" == 2){
        dimlevel = 3;
    }
```

I'd like to extract the strings that's in between the quotation mark and put it in a separate string array. For instance, string[] extracted would contain 00000000, 02000001, 02000043....

What is the best approach for this? Should I use regular expression to somehow parse those lines and split it?

Comment: Are you saying the parameters of STEPCONTROL are the text you are provided or that the whole block is an item in a string array???

Comment: As posted, your strings do not contain quotes... Only the notation in C# uses `"`.

Comment: I think the string includes the exact text specified above including engine.STEPCONTROL, if etc

Comment: That's what I thought he was saying after reading it 5 times.

Comment: @adrianm But he says it's in a string array?  Maybe he means one element per line?

Comment: What I meant was the I am given the above code in a text format that I need to parse into my program. So the postcondition is having a string array with all the items that's inside the quotation mark so I'd have string[] parsed = {"00000000","02000001","02000043","02000002","02000007","02000003","02000008","02000004","02000009","02000005","02000010","02000006","02000011", "02000001", "02000001"}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I don't think a regular expression is necessary. If you can be sure that the input string is always as described and will not have any escape sequences in it or vary in any other way, you could use something like this:

```
    public static string[] ExtractNumbers(string[] originalCodeLines)
    {
        List<string> extractedNumbers = new List<string>();

        string[] codeLineElements = originalCodeLines[0].Split('"');
        foreach (string element in codeLineElements)
        {
            int result = 0;
            if (int.TryParse(element, out result))
            {
                extractedNumbers.Add(element);
            }
        }

        return extractedNumbers.ToArray();
    }
```

It's not necessarily the most efficient implementation but it's quite short and its easy to see what it does.

Comment: This is very close to what I am looking for. However, the numbers are hexadecimal, so int.TryParse doesn't catch all the numbers I am speaking of.

Comment: A small change to the TryParse call will take care of that: `int.TryParse(element, Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber, Globalization.NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo, out result)`

Answer (score 1):

that could be

```
    string data = "\"00000000\",\"02000001\",\"02000043\"".Replace("\"", string.Empty);
    string[] myArray = data.Split(',');
```

or in 1 line

```
 string[] data = "\"00000000\",\"02000001\",\"02000043\"".Replace("\"", string.Empty).Split(',');
```